# Ortery Technologies Object VR turntable claims

Tags: prior-art-request, prior-art, us20070172216

There are at minimum 12 manufactures currently producing and selling systems identical to what Ortery Technologies, Inc. has listed in its claims (US20070172216). There are current systems on the market from multiple vendors that employ serial, USB and wireless communications between PC and camera and that are capable of automated picture taking and synchronizing control exactly as claimed by Ortery. Many of these companies have been offering what is claimed in this patent since 1999. Also, multiple software companies offer object vr automated control software designed to work with these various vendors turntables in the exact communications manner that is described in the claims. I don't understand how Ortery can make an attempt to patent this. I was thinking about designing a turntable that was compatible with software currently on the market. If i did, and sold some would I be infringing on the claims in US20070172216. Or is this patent destined not to be granted?

Answer (score 1):

From your question, I think you know that document US20070172216 is a publication of an application for a patent, not a document representing an issued patent. I looked it up in the USPTO's Public PAIR database and that application went abandoned in 2008.

[image]